# OpenCV how to clear contour from noise and false positives

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have found image contour with standart function cv2.findContours in Python.

[image]

But as you see there is a dot in the middle and i cannot filter it without breaking the contour line.

How can i remove such a false-positive cluster?
Those outside of the contour are not important.

```
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    _, mask = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh=152, maxval=162, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    self.mask = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, mask)
    self.contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(self.mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: Could you also please post the code you tried? To see how did you do it.

Comment: Try using `cv.RETR_EXTERNAL` for the _retrieval mode_ option, see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0).

Comment: Yes i'm using this option. Sharing my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One good method to avoid false positive is to consider the contour with the largest area:

```
import imutils #to use sorting functionality 
#To install imutils run: pip install imutils for python 2.x
#Run: pip3 install imutils for python 3.x

cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts) #where cnts is the variable in which contours are stored, replace it with your variable name
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10] #sorts contours according to their area from largest to smallest.

largestCont = cnts[0] #store the largest contour
```

This shall remove the small dot while giving out only the largest contour